# Java jackson json with hierarchical data. How to remove duplicates

Tags: java, json, tree, jackson, hierarchical-data

I am trying to do some repository of files and folders. I'would like to use java script  library to print tree, so I have to apply Json object to it. But unfortunatelly when I am trying to make my object to json, I get duplicates. Here is json output from my main object:

```
[{"id":5,"name":"Folder2.2","parent":
    {"id":2,"name":"Folder1.1","parent":
      {"id":1,"name":"Folder1","parent":null}}},
  {"id":1,"name":"Folder1","parent":null},
  {"id":2,"name":"Folder1.1","parent":
    {"id":1,"name":"Folder1","parent":null}},
      {"id":3,"name":"Folder2","parent":null},
  {"id":4,"name":"Folder2.1","parent":
    {"id":3,"name":"Folder2","parent":null}}
]
```

As You can see there is a lot of duplicates. And I would like to print from this data hierachical tree. Should be something like this:

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"Folder1","children":
  {"id":2,"name":"Folder1.1","children":null}
},
{"id":3,"name":"Folder2","children":
  {"id":4,"name":"Folder2.1","children":null},
  {"id":5,"name":"Folder2.2","children":null}
}
]
```

Can it be done with some out of the box api from Jackson?

Here is my entity

```
@Entity
public class Folder {
  Long id;
  String name;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  Folder parent;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you keep just the id of the parent, instead of referencing the whole object?